# SQL Events with start time and endtime, converted to hours into shift

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dilemna at work with Microsoft SQL Server. I have a table with a column of starttime in seconds e.g. 7200 (2 hours into shift) and endtime and duration.

I need to group the event duration by hour.

My query is currently:

```
SELECT
     e.eqmtid as LoadUnit
    ,r.name as Reason
    ,e.starttime 
    ,e.endtime
    ,e.duration

FROM 
    sh_status_events e

INNER JOIN
    PIT_ReasonCodes r
    ON e.reason = r.reason

WHERE 
    e.shiftindex >= <STARTSHIFTINDEX>
    AND e.shiftindex <= <ENDSHIFTINDEX>
```

which returns results:

```
LoadUnit    Reason  starttime   endtime duration
EX022   OPERATING   0           1008    1008
EX022   OPERATING   1008        2898    1890
EX022   OPERATING   2898        3535    637
EX022   OPERATING   3615        4515    900
EX022   OPERATING   4515        4541    26
EX022   OPERATING   4885        5555    670
```

But I need to group by hour like:

```
Hour        Reason       Duration
1stHour     Operating    2400
2ndHour     Operating    1000
3rdHour     Operating    3200
4thHour     Operating    3600
5thHour     Operating    3600
6thHour     Operating    1322
```

Which I can do, but for any event that starts on one hour and finishes in another, it doesn't carry the time to the following hour.

e.g. Event starts at 90 minutes and goes for 1 hour, shoud be

```
2ndHour     Operating    1800
3rdHour     Operating    3600
```

But it will put the full 5400 into the second hour.

Is there any conciveable way of fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to identify the total hours. you can do that using `MAX(endtime)` and `CEILING`. Something like this `(SELECT CEILING(MAX(endTime) /3600.0) FROM @LoadUnit)`. You can then Get hours with start and end time using a CTE or a numbers table.

We can then use `CROSS APPLY` to get what you want. Something like this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a6b89/7).

**Sample Data**

```
DECLARE @LoadUnit TABLE (LoadUnit CHAR(5),Reason VARCHAR(20),starttime INT,endtime INT, duration INT)

INSERT INTO @LoadUnit VALUES
('EX022','OPERATING',   0,           1008,    1008),
('EX022','OPERATING',   1008,        2898,    1890),
('EX022','OPERATING',   2898,        3535,    637),
('EX022','OPERATING',   3615,        4515,    900),
('EX022','OPERATING',   4515,        4541,    26),
('EX022','OPERATING',   4885,        5555,    670);
```

**Query**

```
DECLARE @MaxCeiling INT = (SELECT CEILING(MAX(endTime) /3600.0) FROM @LoadUnit)
;WITH Hrs as 
(
    SELECT 1 hrs,0 as StartTime,3599 as EndTime
    UNION ALL SELECT hrs + 1,StartTime + 3600,EndTime + 3600 from Hrs WHERE hrs + 1 <= @MaxCeiling
)
SELECT H2.hrs,Reason,SUM(H2.endtime - H2.starttime) as Duration
FROM @LoadUnit L
CROSS APPLY 
(
SELECT H.hrs,
CASE WHEN L.starttime < H.StartTime THEN H.StartTime ELSE L.starttime END StartTime,
CASE WHEN L.endtime > H.endtime THEN H.Endtime ELSE L.Endtime END endTime
FROM hrs H
)H2
WHERE H2.endtime - H2.starttime >=0
GROUP BY H2.hrs,Reason
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! This does exactly what I need it to do on fiddle but it doesn't work when I try and run it through my database :( using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0 (X64) I can't figure out why it's not working, do all of those commands work with earlier versions?

Comment: I had to add 'SET NOCOUNT ON' to the top as it was messing with the engine that the statement runs through. Can't thank you enough, this saved me a lot of heartache.